# How do I add more values to my output?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, output

Here is my function that is suppose to take the values from "in1.txt" and output them into "out1.txt" with a description saying if they are prime or not.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class task1
{
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
   if (n <= 1) {
   return false;
   }
   for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
   if (n % i == 0) {
       return false;
   }
}
return true;
}
public static ArrayList<String> check_primes(String in_file, String out_file)
{
    File temp = new File(in_file);
    Scanner input_file;
    String filename = "out1.txt";
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try
    {
        input_file = new Scanner(temp);
        out = new PrintWriter(filename);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.printf("Failed to open file %s\n",in_file);
        return null;
    }
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(input_file.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = input_file.nextLine();
        result.add(line);

        for(int i = 0; i<result.size();i++)
        {
            String x = result.get(i); 
            int xx = Integer.parseInt(x);
            if(isPrime(xx))
            {
                out.printf(xx + " is a prime\r\n");
            }
            else
            {
                out.printf(xx + " is not a prime\r\n");
            }        
        }

        out.close();
    }

    input_file.close();

    return result;
 }
public static void main(String[] args)
{
check_primes("in1.txt", "out1.txt");
System.out.printf("Exiting...\n");
}
}
```

it only adds the first value of the int1 file and I am assuming it is some sort of loop error or that I'm missing something in my loop. i tested to see if there was an error with "x" or "xx" and had them printed out and x would print out as [7] [7 , 10] [7, 10, 13] etc forming a pyramid, and xx printed out in a similar manner as 7\n 7\n 10\n 7\n 10\n 13\n
can someone help me figure out where the issue is?

Comment: consider not closing the output in the loop :)

Comment: @zapl +1 for spotting the main issue but, even if the output in the loop is not closed, don't you think the for loop is restarted every time a new line is added to the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the intention of having a loop followed by adding each line to the list was to process the list containing all lines later. If that is true, then you need to include **result.add(line)** in your while loop and close it. Process all line after that in the for loop

```
while (input_file.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = input_file.nextLine();
   result.add(line);
} //close the loop here
```

Assuming that you do not close the while loop. For loop will execute only once becaause your **result.size()** is one and after for loop is done, it will close the output stream.

Comment: thank you for that, and now I'm annoyed I did't see that small fix xD

Answer (score 0):

```
while(input_file.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input_file.nextLine();
        result.add(line);     
}
for(int i = 0; i<result.size();i++)
    {
        String x = result.get(i); 
        int xx = Integer.parseInt(x);
        if(isPrime(xx))
        {
            out.printf(xx + " is a prime\r\n");
        }
        else
        {
            out.printf(xx + " is not a prime\r\n");
        }        
    }

    out.close();
```